# FlexSlider Images appearing in different location for IE and Chrome

Tags: css, image, flexslider

I have some flexslider images on my page(s), and I can't seem to figure out why the images are displaying in a different location in IE vs. Chrome.  Does anyone have any advice how I can make the location consistent regardless of browser?  Chrome is showing in the correct location, and IE has the images pushed over to the right....'off of the boundaries of my page.

```
#main {
   margin-left: 575px; 
   margin-top: 175px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;} 

<div id="main" role="main">
  <section class="slider">
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
        <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" alt="AMORE Wooden Sign" />
   </li>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 100,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    lightbox: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the JS to initializing the slider?

Comment: Updated the posting to include the js for calling the slider.

Comment: What versions of IE are you using? Also are you loading the conditional CSS for <IE9? Also providing a link to the page in question would allow me to help you better.

Comment: So, I have tried it against IE9, and the position is okay.  When testing against IE8, that is when it is off.  Not sure if I should really care about IE8, as it is pretty old.  But, I also don't know how to add any conditional CSS for <IE8   I am pretty new to coding.  The page isn't live yet, but hope to have it live tonight.  Thanks for your help, and if you have anything you can point me to for the conditional CSS, that would be great.

Comment: Take a look at: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/
Add a stylehseet for IE < 8 and add the following in it: 
`ul.slides li{margin-left:0 !important;}`
(just a wild guess ;) )